# how to calculate loss between output of first convolutional block and output of second convolutional block?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, loss

```
x1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
x1= MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x1)                                                         
x2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x1)
x2= MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x2)
x3= Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x2)
x3= MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x3)
```

how do we calculate l2 loss between x1 and x3 layers in tensorflow? The problem is that x1 and x3 outputs differ in size.Direct reshaping throws errors.I tried to flatten the outputs and reshape but the sizes are still not comparable

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am trying to guide the feature map of the shallow layer by providing hints from the deeper layer feature map. This would be useful to deploy the shallower layer alone to reduce model complexity

Comment: Well, the issue is that it doesn't really make much sense. Similarly, how do you compute the distance between a 10d vector and a 100d vector? What would that even mean? You have to make them comparable somehow, by either making them the same shape or somehow getting rid of shape completely (e.g. comparing means or something). You could apply 4x4 pooling and a 1D conv to 128 channels to `x1` and compare that to `x3`, that would get them to the same shape at least... But even then, likely all you will achieve is hamstringing your `x3` layer to be only as expressive as just `x1`.